# Password encryption

Tags: password

We are tasked with finding a password. Our only hint seems to be:

> Was wir wissen, ist ein Ozean;
>
> was wir nicht wissen, ist ein Tropfen.

German for:

> What we know is an ocean, what we don't know, is a drop.

What is the password?

The site this is from can be found [here](http://www.ohjelmointiputka.net/postit/elhak-koe.php).

English translations for Finnish words:

- taso = level
- Edellisen tason koodi = the code for the previous level
- Kirjoita salasana = write the password
- vastaus = answer
- Lähetä = submit.

Here are the first 4 passwords:

- Level 1: salasana
- Level 2: aybabtu
- Level 3: 237812992
- Level 4: 62981123

Comment: The translation of this is *What we know, is an ocean; which we do not know, is a drop.*
You will have to work out the rest by yourself.

Comment: If the puzzle site is one of those "guess the URL of the next page by using clues on this page" sites (a la [The Python Challenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/)), then the text you've provided may be only a small part of the puzzle. Can you tell us what site it was?

Comment: That was in Finnish programming forum, http://www.ohjelmointiputka.net/postit/elhak-koe.php . I think you need an account to do the puzzle.

Comment: Why don't you give the answers for level 1-4.Then users can simply check for themselves bcoz i could go upto level 3 without any account. 
Answer:- level 1 = salasana, lvl2 = aybabtu.
Whats the answers for lvl3 and 4?

Comment: Speculation is good and all, but let's keep answers to actual answers, not just guesses. Thanks, all!

Comment: @Hubble07: Here is how you can go to level 5: Level 1: salasana Level 2: aybabtu Level 3: 237812992 Level 4: 62981123

Comment: Given apparantly someone deleted some comments, I'll readd this. It appears this 'puzzle' is supposedly part of an entrance exam to a hacker group (Elitehacker Brotherhood). The matching page shows there's 80+ people that have solved level 10 (there is 10 levels): http://www.ohjelmointiputka.net/posti.php?tunnus=elhak . In that light the ask for help is a bit sneaky.

Comment: @TimCouwelier That may be, however I don't think that's for us to *ACT* upon.

Comment: @computerenthusiast I'm guessing that there might be some sort of a language barrier for people that don't know Finnish, as such puzzles rarely go unsolved here. Try going in that direction.

Comment: @computerenthusiast Also, being a "hacker"-something-something, you might as well have a look at [NewtonScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NewtonScript)

Answer (score 1):

Usually the quote goes different: what we know is a drop, what we don't know is an ocean.
That seems to be a quote from Sir Isaac Newton.

If anything, I'd guess the answer could be a variation on Newton (like notwen, ...)

Comment: I tried notwen, Notwen, Oldton, tonold, and also German version Neuton but with no luck.

Comment: @computerenthusiast Old = Alt in German, so maybe try Altton as well

Comment: @Timmy It wasn't Altton or altton.

Comment: In addition - if it's just a 'classic' word play... 'what we don't know' = the password needed. So try 'Tropfen' or 'ein Tropfen' ?

Comment: That was not the solution.

Answer (score 1):

As Tim Couwelier mentioned in [his answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/2122/2032), the quote is the opposite of what Newton said. So the password could be a variation on the opposite of Newton. Anti-newton comes to mind, but that isn't a real concept. So I am guessing **Antineutron**, since a good password hint does not lead directly to the password, but in a more vague manner.

Comment: It wasn't an Antineutron.

Answer (score 1):

Caesar since a word from the first half is swapped with a word from the second half, or it may be Newton put through a Caesar cipher.

Comment: Neither of them.

Comment: It wasn't a reaction.

Comment: It wasn't the asked password.

Answer (score 1):

May it be "Graviton", it is an hypothetical elementary particle that mediates the force of gravitation. 
It is small "like a drop", unknown, related to Newton (Gravity) and proposed by Einstein (for some reason the phrase is in German) also Einstein General Relativity changed some concepts from Newtons original theory, like the quote.

I have tried with Graviton but it is no, maybe a variant?. Sorry for not using the comments section, I have no 50 points yet.

Comment: You are encouraged to earn the 50 points needed to comment in the proper fashion. No legitimate way to get your comment in in when you do not have sufficient reputation.

Comment: it was not "graviton"

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about Lepton or Photon because of eV Tasso and the thing is EV - taso 5?

**EDIT**
Just tried it, didn't work. Is there any new update on this? This has been dead for about 6 months, and I can't stop fiddling with this. I MUST KNOW lol